# The energy difference between black hole and system has zero potential energy

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, potential-energy

As particles gets toward each other, the potential energy decreases and kinetic energy increases. So that the net energy will be conserved. As a result, "black hole with mass $M$" and "system with same mass $M$ but nearly zero potential energy due to its large distance between particles", will have different net energy. Then, what is the exact value of net energy difference?

Lets assume that black hole is Schwarzschild Black Hole so that the calculation would be simple :)

Comment: “*black hole with mass  and system with same mass  but nearly zero potential energy due to its large distance between particles, will have different net energy*” - This doesn’t sound right, are you sure you’ve phrased it correctly? +=2 at infinity, but <2 at a smaller distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a testparticle of mass $m$ and a black hole of mass $M$. If $m$ is at rest and infinitely far away from $M$, its potential and kinetic energy are $0$, so its total energy is simply its rest energy $m c^2$.

If you let the testparticle fall freely toward the black hole, the total energy stays conserved, so the potential energy (which is negative) decreases proportional as the kinetic energy (which is positive) increases.

When free falling from infinity, the infalling velocity equals the negative escape velocity (measured by local stationary observers), in the Schwarzschild scenario simply $v=v_e=c \sqrt{r_s/r}$, which is $c$ at the horizon.

If you stop the particle in its free fall and manage to keep it stationary relative to the black hole so that $v=0$, the energy difference between the particle infinitely far away from the black hole or free falling from infinity and the particle at rest close to the black hole is simply the kinetic energy it would have gained when free falling with the negative escape velocity. That energy must be absorbed by the mechanism that you use to bring the particle to rest.

The total energy of a testparticle in the vicinity of a Schwarzschild black hole measured by an observer at infinity is
$$E=g_{tt} \dot{t} \ m c^2  = m c^2 \frac{\sqrt{1-r_s/r}}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$$

As you can see the total energy of a particle with $v=0$ hovering at the horizon at $r_s$ would be $E=0$, although it is not possible to hover at the horizon. The closer to the horizon you hover, the less you contribute to the total energy and therefore mass of the system.

Since the orbit velocity $v_o=\sqrt{GM/r}/\sqrt{1-r_s/r}$ is smaller than the escape velocity $v_e$ when $r \geq 2 r_s$, particles that orbit the black hole at radii equal to or larger than twice the Schwarzschildradius contribute less energy to the system than if they were infinitely far away and at rest.

Inside the ergosphere of rotating black holes it is even possible to have negative energy orbits, but that requires the Kerr metric and since you want to limit the case to Schwarzschild to keep it simple that's another chapter.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helped me. For an additional question, you said that "it is even possible to have negative energy orbits", inside the ergosphere. Does it means that the total energy of test particle can be negative even with the rest energy $mc^2$?

Comment: Yes, you can use that to extract rotational energy via the Penrose process